# GATSBY: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I'm having some trouble filtering out images in my portfolio site [laid out in this post…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64935654/how-to-use-gatsby-to-display-a-folder-of-images-and-markdown-files)

This is the error I keep getting:
**"TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined"**

Anyone know why this might be?

Images query:

```
query {
  images: allFile (
    filter: { ext: { eq: ".jpg" } },
    sort: { order: ASC, fields: [relativePath] }
  )
  {
        edges {
        node {
        fields {
            imgslug
        }
        relativeDirectory
        id
        childImageSharp {
          fixed(width: 100) {
            src
          }
        }
        }
    } 
  }
}
```

Image display script:

```
{data.images.edges.filter((node) => node.relativeDirectory.includes(data.images.edges.node.fields.imgslug)).map(image => {
   return (
      <Img key={image.id} fixed={image.childImageSharp.fixed}/>
   )
})}
```

Comment: what do you get when you console.log `relativeDirectory` or view the response in graphiql?

Answer (score 1):

`includes` loop returns a boolean, `true` or `false` depending on the condition. You may want to use something like:

```
{data.images.edges.map((node) => {
   if(node.relativeDirectory.includes(data.images.edges.node.fields.imgslug){
     return <Img key={image.id} fixed={image.childImageSharp.fixed}/>
   }
})}
```